# Saving images then displaying them in a table

Tags: iphone, ios

Can anyone point me towards an example or tutorial for this? I basically want to save images to the documents folder then have a table that contains them for user review later on.

I've got it working but only when I go and add each image to an array then generate the table with contents of said array first. Is there a quicker or more automated way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial giving a project you could adapt:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

While it's actually about doing lazy loading and other image operations on a secondary thread (keeping your UI responsive) you may as well display images in a table this way to begin with.

The main modification you would make is to look for the locally stored image first, then go and do the network fetch if it is not available. A further refinement would be to check a timestamp stored with each local image and update from the web if a newer one was available.

Comment: Ok cool, this is definitely a great start. I've sort of implemented it in my code. Now I just have to figure out how to delete images but that shouldn't be too hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, you prepare your datasource first (which is array of images), then you pass it to tableview and reload it. If you are working with lots of images, consider lazy loading.

Apple has [an example on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).